# CBR to Pdf conversion failed for "cache resources exhausted" with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I’m trying to convert a 275 MB CBR file to pdf but the conversion is getting failed.

These are the steps I followed:

1. Command to unzip the rar: unrar e '/tmp/1676456470685.2727/6782.rar' /tmp/1676456470889.922
2. Command to convert the unzipped jpg images to pdf:

```
convert /tmp/1676456470889.922/*.jpg -profile /app/sRGB2014.icc -strip -set profile /app/sRGB2014.icc -compress jpeg -resize 1240.2x1753.95 
-gravity Center -extent 1240.2x1753.95 -units PixelsPerInch -density 150 -repage 1240.2x1753.95 -bordercolor white -border 0 output.pdf
```

Error:

```
convert: cache resources exhausted `/tmp/1676456470889.922/OPSX-UK-028_Page_154.jpg' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3879.
convert: cache resources exhausted `/tmp/1676456470889.922/OPSX-UK-028_Page_155.jpg' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3879.
convert: cache resources exhausted `/tmp/1676456470889.922/OPSX-UK-028_Page_156.jpg' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3879.
convert: cache resources exhausted `/tmp/1676456470889.922/OPSX-UK-028_Page_001.jpg' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3879.
```

About system:

Host machine:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Memory: 64GB

ImageMagick is running in a docker container:

Container OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

ImageMagick version: 7.1.0-62

Current ImageMagick resource policy:

```
<policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="16GiB"/>
<policy domain="resource" name="map" value="32GiB"/>
<policy domain="resource" name="area" value="24GB"/>
<policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="64GiB"/>
```

Comment: Does your docker container have a memory limit set?

Comment: What's a CBR file please? Did you try converting just half the pages to see how far off you are? Or try doing half the pages into each of 2 PDFs then combining the PDFs?

Comment: What are the dimensions of your image (WxH) and number of images you are trying to read into memory at the same time. The amount of RAM would be WxH*4*N (result in bytes) where N is number of images. Compare that to your RAM

Comment: You can use `convert -verbose …` or `convert -debug all …` to get better error messages and diagnostics. You can use `identify -list configure` to see how your IM version was built and see if JP2 is supported. Or `identify -version`. Click [edit] and paste results into your question rather than into comments.

Comment: `convert /tmp/1676456470889.922/*.jpg ...` Is loading all your images ,decompressing them to full WxH*4 channels. So N*one JPG file size is not what is important. You are also writing them all to the same output name.  If you want to process multiple JPGs, I suggest using mogrify rather than convert. It will load them one at a time rather than all at the same time